# Validate that number is either 0 or between 1 and 5

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have an angularjs form, and I need to validate if the number is 0 or is between 1 and 5. This is my current code:

```
<form name="myform" data-ng-submit="create(myform)" novalidate>
  <input type="number" name="special" data-ng-required="true" 
     data-ng-model="special" data-ng-required="true" min="1" max="5">

  <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

Is there an easy built in way to validate the number is either 0 or in the range 1-5, or do I need to use a custom directive?

Comment: Can't you just validate min="0" and max="5" ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go this should start you off in the right direction...

```
.directive('onlyDigits', function () {
return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    function inputValue(val) {
      if (val) {
        var digits = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

        if (digits !== val) {
          ctrl.$setViewValue(digits);
          ctrl.$render();
        }
        return parseInt(digits,10);
      }
      return undefined;
    }            
    ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
  }
};
```

});

Sorry its a short answer but im in work.

Comment: ps just add a little validation logic such as "if(val > 0 && val <= 5){//do something here;}

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ng-pattern`

```
 ... min="1" max="5" ng-pattern="/^0$/">
```

and then do a check for both min / max and pattern (and number if you are so inclined).

**HTML**

```
<form name="myform" data-ng-submit="create(myform)" novalidate>
    <input type="number" name="special" data-ng-required="true"
            data-ng-model="special" data-ng-required="true" min="1" max="5" ng-pattern="/^0$/">
        Valid : {{ !myform.special.$error.number && (!myform.special.$error.pattern || (!myform.special.$error.min && !myform.special.$error.max)) }}
    <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How about just ng-pattern="/[0234]/"? This will further simplify the validation, i.e. !myform.special.$error.pattern.

Comment: My understanding was that OP wanted 0 and all numbers from 1 to 5 (including decimals). I could be wrong though. I think you could modify the ng-pattern for that too, but it seemed easier to do it with a combination of 2 validators :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation):

```
yourApp.directive('myValidator', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.myValidator = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          // consider empty models to be valid
          return true;
        }

        if (viewValue === "0" || (viewValue >= 1 && viewValue <= 5)) {
          // it is valid
          return true;
        }

        // it is invalid
        return false;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Here is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/KA6Gzn1A2GLONc69eHxJ).